# How to Route a Message based on content using Spring Integration 2.0.5?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I started out using the si-xml:xpath-router but I ran into a roadblock.  Am I using  correct router but wrong implementation?  If I'm using the incorrect router, which one should I be using, i.e. default router, payload-type, or maybe a simple SpEL expression?

**Use Case:**

I need to route a message based on payload content.  The request contains an element and the 'action' I need to perform is contained in one if its attributes, see attribute **"command"** below.

Example inbound request (comes from a web-service).

```
<Request>
  <Records>
    <Record>
      <data key="name" value="Jack Bauer" />
      <data key="command" value="sendSMS" />
    </Record>
  </Records>
</Request>
```

The psuedocode was:

- marshall message.
- route based on value, via xpath-router

but I'm getting the error:

**unsupported payload type [javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult]**

---

In order to resolve this, I have tried:

- adding the attribute "result-transformer" to the transformer bean using ResultToDocumentTransformer. **error**= failed to resolve channel name ''
- adding attribute "result-type" to the transformer using StringResult. **error** = unsupported payload type [org.springframework.xml.transform.StringResult]
- adding both of the above. **error** = failed to resolve channel name ''
- adding the attribute "evaluate-as-string" using true. **error** = unsupported payload type.

---

Original Configuration file below:

```
<gateway id="gateway" default-request-channel="requestChannel"
          service-interface="foo.SomeClass" />


<beans:bean id="marshaller"
    class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <beans:property name="classesToBeBound">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.foo.Request</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.foo.Record</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.foo.Data</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<chain input-channel="requestChannel">
  <poller max-messages-per-poll="10" task-executor="executor">
    <interval-trigger interval="5000" />
  </poller>

  <si-xml:marshalling-transformer marshaller="marshaller"/>

  <si-xml:xpath-router id="instockRouter" resolution-required="true">
    <si-xml:xpath-expression expression="/Request/Records/Record/data[@key='command']"/>
    <si-xml:mapping value="sendSMS" channel="SMSChannel"/>
  </si-xml:xpath-router>
</chain>

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="8"/>
```

Comment: One idea I did have was to take the Request message and transform that into a simple POJO with fields of 'name' and 'command'. Then I could write a SpEL expression like 'payload.command'

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring's `"=object-to-string-transformer />"` after marshalling.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see:

1. Message comes into gateway which forwards it to the requestChannel
2. requestChannel processing is forwarded into chain, which in first step marshall object using `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller` into `javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult`
3. When your payload is of `DOMResult` type you try to use xpath-router.

As far as I know, XPath router works fine if message payload is String type containing plain XML inside. So I would recommend to do not marshall your message before using xpath router, but to use xpath router first.

If you will marshall the object, it will be `DOMResult` type and you will have to deal with `DOMResult` (sad but true :))

...anyway I think that DOMResult is not what you want to have as a message payload - maybe you did a mistake between marshalling and unmarshalling?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for the late reply.  I did indeed try this and it didn't work. "anyway I think that DOMResult is not what you want to have as a message payload - maybe you did a mistake between marshalling and unmarshalling?"  I think you are right!!